# What is wrong with this query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spIncTurn_Member_fix]
(
/*  param1 = part = edu,mem,women,personal
    param2 = member_id or code(dept_name?)
*/
    @param1 varchar(20),
    @param2 varchar(20)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO BibleHistory (id, Bible, Chapter, Verse, [Content], member_id, dept_code, verse_id, dept_name, DateWrote, name, turn, forced_write, bible_lang)
            SELECT     
                BibleWrote.id, BibleWrote.Bible, BibleWrote.Chapter, 
                BibleWrote.Verse, BibleWrote.[Content], 
                BibleWrote.member_id, BibleWrote.dept_code, 
                BibleWrote.verse_id, BibleWrote.dept_name, 
                BibleWrote.DateWrote, BibleWrote.name, BibleWrote.turn, 
                BibleWrote.forced_write, BibleWrote.bible_lang
            FROM         
                BibleWrote 
            INNER JOIN
                Member ON BibleWrote.member_id = Member.id --AND BibleWrote.turn < Member.turn
            WHERE     
                (BibleWrote.dept_code = @param1) 
                AND (Member.id = @param2)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            /* ?- Rollback the transaction */
            ROLLBACK
            RAISERROR ('Error in copying BibleWrote into BibleHistory.', 16, 1)

            RETURN
        END

        DELETE FROM BibleWrote
        FROM BibleWrote 
        INNER JOIN Member ON BibleWrote.member_id = Member.id --AND BibleWrote.turn < Member.turn
        WHERE (BibleWrote.dept_code = @param1) AND (Member.id = @param2)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            /* -? Rollback the transaction  */
            ROLLBACK
            RAISERROR ('Error in deleting BibleWrote table.', 16, 1)

            RETURN
        END

        COMMIT
        RETURN
```

And below is my query that I am trying to run. It's not affecting any rows for some reason. I am quite familiar with mysql which I use at work, and just trying to get myself familiar with SQL Server.. and I don't have whole lot of context why this query is not running correctly.

```
EXEC [dbo].[spIncTurn_Member_fix] @param1='personal', @params2='671'
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the select portion manually with the parameters you have provided? What are the results?

Comment: yeh try manually executing the query with the static paramater value

Comment: Also, consider your rolback statement would actually make your commit statement invalid (since no Begin Tran would be associated) what are you returning?

Comment: You're missing `commit`. Put a commit before `if error`

Comment: @artm lol, that is terrible advice. The whole point is to not perform the action if failure occurs. Commit writes it to the database which is the opposite of rollingback the transaction log.

Comment: what does this mean? i get "--AND BibleWrote.turn < Member.turn" in green collor after i tried to execute manually?

Comment: @clifton_h Yeah, you're right, I didn't even see the rest of the SP, I thought it didn't have a commit. Even then yeah commit should be after if error, which it is. Ignore me.

Comment: That is just a commented out portion of the statement, it does not get executed.

Comment: Your `DELETE` statement has **two** `FROM` clauses - that won't work !

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameter Name.In your procedures you declare @param2 but when   execute you use @params2

```
EXEC [dbo].[spIncTurn_Member_fix] @param1='personal', @params2='671'
```

Comment: And then, you can take advantage of [XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) and [THROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) if you are still concerned.